# I dont understand python threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading

I try to run this code, where two threads shall be initialized based on scheduled tasks. I just want to have the deamons in parallel which shall print out an unspecific global value after a certain amount of time.

```
import os
import schedule
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

myval = 0
thrs = []

def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

def loopfunc(t):
    global myval
    myval = t
    clear()
    print("myval=",t)

def primefunc(t):
    schedule.every(5).to(20).seconds.do(
        loopfunc,t)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    for num in [1,2]:
        thrs.append(Thread(target=primefunc(num)))
        thrs[-1].start()
    print(threading.active_count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When trying to run it just as stated above, only the first thread gets initialized and runs in loop. So my output is always `myval=1`

When i am inserting `lambda` for target function:

```
thrs.append(Thread(target=lambda:primefunc(num)))
```

both threads get initialized but i have randomly double outputs of

```
myval=2
myval=2
```

or

```
myval=1
myval=1
```

What is happening here?
Kind regards, MK

Comment: this line `thrs.append(Thread(target=primefunc(num)))` is wrong, you are calling the function instead of passing it as an argument. if you want to pass `num` as an argument to the function you need to do `thrs.append(Thread(target=primefunc, args=[num]))`

Comment: thank you very much, youre right. But when doing so, i am still getting randomly the double outputs

Comment: how do you know? you're resetting the screen with `clear()` every time a thread executes

Comment: Yeah, this is why it should only print once "myval=X", but sometimes it displays me double printouts with the same value.

Comment: in general this seems like a bit overkill for just running 2 functions in parallel, what's wrong with good old threading?

Comment: when i am honest, it is just a simplified version of what i am trying to do. the real world problem are threads which inherit a scheduled selenium instance for doing webstuff. 3 threads shall be initialized, in every target function i am passing the URL and other things. Instead of looking one time per thread at the URL, it seems to open randomly multiple webdriver instances just like it is doing now with the printouts in this simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is because you call the `primefunc` function directly here rather than pass it in as an argument to Thread.

```
thrs.append(Thread(target=primefunc(num)))
```

You need to wrap it in a lambda or provide the bare function name as the target and the `num` argument in the `args` keyword argument of Thread, like so:

```
thrs.append(Thread(target=lambda: primefunc(num)))

# or

thrs.append(Thread(target=primefunc, args=[num]))
```

For your doubling of outputs, I suspect what's happening here is that you have two scheduler loops running concurrently in different threads and they both pick up the same `job` before it's removed from the internal queue. [The code for scheduler is on github, and you can see that the job runner does not perform any kind of locking around the running of tasks and removing them from the queue to make the two operations atomic together.](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L85)

Here's an example of the series of events that could lead to that scenario. Let's say we're at second number 7 in our execution time, the scheduler decides to add an execution of `loopfunc(1)`. Here's a sequence of events that could happen after that:

1. Thread 1 runs `schedule.run_pending()`.
2. Thread 1 finds job `loopfunc(1)` on the scheduler queue.
3. Thread 1 runs `loopfunc(1)` and outputs `myval=1`
4. A context switch to Thread 2 occurs before `loopfunc(1)` is removed from the queue. Thread 2 `runs schedule.run_pending()`
5. Thread 2 finds job `loopfunc(1)` on the scheduler queue.
6. Thread 2 runs `loopfunc(1)` and outputs `myval=1`
7. Thread 2 removes it from the queue.
8. A context switch occurs back to Thread 1.
9. Thread 1 tries to remove `loopfunc(1)` from the queue, but it's no longer there.

There are a few other ways that could happen, and it's not guaranteed to happen every time, but you can see how you can end up with `myval=1` being printed twice.

I think the solution here is to ditch the scheduler, since it's purpose is sort of the same as the threading here. Instead, perhaps just generate the random numbers and track the time yourself inside `primefunc`, for example:

```
def primefunc(t):
    time = 0
    r = random.randint(5, 20)
    while True:
        if time % r == 0:
            loopfunc(t)
            r = random.randint(5, 20)
        time.sleep(1)
        time += 1
```

You could also choose the opposite approach and do away with threading and keep the scheduler. Then you can just run the scheduler loop inside your main function, which would look like this:

```
def main():
    for num in [1,2]:
        schedule.every(5).to(20).seconds.do(loopfunc,num)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: ok very appreciated, i was not aware of the context switch between the threads. i thought that the threads are somehow limited to the initial set inputs and are working separately/independently.

Comment: The threads share the same memory while multiple processes run on independent memories. So, if you prefer the tasks to be run independently, using multiprocessing can also be a faster approach than threading.

Comment: thank you @aargun, it seems to work as intended just by using the multiprocessing. But overall, maybe Rob and anti are right with trying to implement a more slim interpretation